# Castle.Windsor registering for Generic Types with abstraction

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have two abstract classes and an interface for my Dao:

```
public abstract class DBEntity

public abstract class GenericDao<T> : IDao<T> where T : DBEntity

public interface IDao<T> where T : DBEntity
```

I am trying to resolve `IDao<ModelClass.Model>` in the constructor of my service:

```
this.cvDao = IoC.Resolve<IDao<CV>>();
```

*the problem is starting here.*

I am trying to register `IDao<>` and I have already used some methods such as:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDao<>))
                            .ImplementedBy(typeof(GenericDao<>))
                            .LifestylePerWebRequest());

container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("cvdb.Dao")
                           .BasedOn(typeof(IDao<>))
                           .WithService.Base());
```

But all of these methods causes same exception with same effect. My application has an infinite loop and `StackOverFlowException`. When I debug my code, I have seen that I can't register `IDao<>`.

Comment: Where does the exception occur/what is its callstack?  Is there a class that derives from `GenericDao`?  What does its constructor look like?

Comment: Patrick, firstly thank you for your kind help. The exception occurs in IoC because of going into infinite loop between registering IDao and checking if container is null. There is no class derives from GenericDao. It constructs MongoClient and MongoDatabase and MongoServer classes for using in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GenericDao is an abstract class. I should have tried to resolve a class which derives from it or change it's type to a non-abstract class to create instance.